# visual studio 2012: keyboard shortcut not responding

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

i have a problem while debugging asp net mvc 4 or classic windows form solution:
generally shortcut keyboards, like F11 and F5 doesn't do anything..
It seems thay call classic PC functionality: ex. F2 modifies screen's brightness!!

Any help would be appreciated!!

David

Comment: Probably you have a keyboard with a special key that switch from normal functionality to dedicated keypress. That special key is off

Comment: Or some plugin that overrides some shortcuts...E.g. resharper etc.

Comment: I got the solution: my (new) laptop has the "lock" keyboard activated..!!!! Thanks @Steve!!

Comment: :) sounds like you have my same laptop to develop on. I have win 8 with vs 2012 as well. I have a problem sometimes with doing combo keys that involve the shift key.. such as opening the Design window (Shift+F7) on my keyboard I would have to do FN+Shift+F7 but that doesn't work. For now I have to right click and some of those actions. I've been meaning to see if i can turn that off or switch functions around so I have to do FN+F2 to turn down brightness.

Comment: @user2327311 Where is that function at?

Comment: Please pick a real, understandable question title. Don't just repeat tags.

Comment: @RobertSnyder : just beside the F12 button, togethere with Fn..

Answer (score 0):

Press keyboard combination like: Fn + F2 or go in visual studio option : Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard and reset the keyboard mapping

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you do not have function lock turned off on your keyboard (that's what happened too me before)